# Decrement counter not working as expected with respect to increment counter-angular js

Tags: javascript, arrays, angularjs, counter

I'm trying to perform increment and decrement function with set of 4 numbers/years as in which the navigation should be restricted within the array limit of 4 years.

I'm able to increment the count on each click of Increment button but not able to decrement in the same reverse order.Also the button for decrement gets disabled once I click on increment which should happen only I reach the last index of increment/decrement and vice versa

Playground is [here](https://plnkr.co/edit/dsdJIs?p=preview)

```
 $scope.navigateYear=function(year, mode) {
       const index = $scope.yearArray.indexOf(year);
         if (index >= 0 && index < $scope.yearArray.length - 1 && mode === 'plus') {
             this.year = $scope.yearArray[index + 1];
        }else{
          $scope.isPlusButtondisabled=true;
        }
        if (index >= 0 && index < $scope.yearArray.length - 1 && mode === 'minus') {
            this.year = $scope.yearArray[index - 1];
        } else{
            $scope.isMinusButtondisabled=true;
        }
    }
```

I'm performing both increment and decrement operations in the same function by passing mode as **plus** or **minus**

Comment: You are running the if-statements regardless. If the `if` part is false it does your else. So passing `plus` will still run the minus if-statement disabling the button. Your first `minus` mode will disable the plus button.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are a few of issues here:

1. You are disabling the minus button if the plus button is clicked and vice versa because you check the `mode` in each `if` statement.
2. The minus button `if` statement needs to check if the `index` is `> 0` instead of `>= 0`
3. Whenever you decrement / increment, you should make sure that the other button is re-enabled so you can go back up / down years.

What I would recommend is to start by checking if the `mode` is `plus` or `minus`, then go from there.

When they `plus` the year, then check the `index` and increment / disable the `plus` button as needed (and re-enable the `minus` button). And vice versa for the `minus` mode.

```
    $scope.navigateYear=function(year, mode) {
       const index = $scope.yearArray.indexOf(year);

       if (mode === 'plus') {
         if (index >= 0 && index < $scope.yearArray.length - 1) {
               this.year = $scope.yearArray[index + 1];
               $scope.isMinusButtondisabled = false;
          }else{
            $scope.isPlusButtondisabled=true;
          }
       } else if (mode === 'minus') {
         if (index > 0 && index < $scope.yearArray.length) {
              this.year = $scope.yearArray[index - 1];
              $scope.isPlusButtondisabled = false;
          } else{
              $scope.isMinusButtondisabled=true;
          }
       }
    }
```

I hope this helps.